# what does chrome debugger call stack async option mean?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I saw this option on the `call stack` header, although I am ticking it on, I don't know what does it mean, and what's the implication by ticking it on .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful for debugging asynchronous JavaScript. It let's you view the entire call stack and walk the stack trace for event listeners ( setInterval, setTimeout, XMLHttpRequest and others ). I've found it particularly useful for watching the value of my variables through each async call.

You can read a full description here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/ (which is where I learned what it did a couple weeks ago!)

Comment: This feature seems to be absent in the latest version of Chrome ( 60.0.3112.90 for OSX)

Comment: @slashdottir Apparently Google folded this feature into the Developer Mode and remove the check box, so it should be on be default now: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/05/devtools-release-notes#step-into-async